# pandas dataframe from nested JSON with lists

Tags: python, json, pandas

Although a few other examples of nested JSON to pandas dataframe can be found, this one I cannot find and hence not succeed. I have a nested JSON as follows:

```
{'x':
     {'1':[2,5,6],'2':[7,6]},
 'y':
     {'1':[0,4,8],'2':[8,1]},
 'z':
     {'1':[8,0,9],'2':[2,2]}}
```

and I would like a dataframe as:

```
   1_0 1_1 1_2 2_0 2_1
x   2   5   6   7   6
y   0   4   8   8   1
z   8   0   9   2   2
```

the labelling of the columns do not necessarily have to be exactly this as long as I can infer the data correctly.

I have tried this:

```
import json
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

with gzip.open('example.json') as f:    
    d = json.load(f)  

df = pd.json_normalize(d)
df
```

resulting in this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to first use `DataFrame.from_dict` to load the values as list, and then concat them:

```
d = {'x':
     {'1':[2,5,6],'2':[7,6]},
 'y':
     {'1':[0,4,8],'2':[8,1]},
 'z':
     {'1':[8,0,9],'2':[2,2]}}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient="index")
df2 = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(df[i].values.tolist(),
                              columns=[f"{i}_{num}" for num in range(len(df[i].iat[0]))]
                              ) for i in df.columns],axis=1)

print (df2)

   1_0  1_1  1_2  2_0  2_1
0    2    5    6    7    6
1    0    4    8    8    1
2    8    0    9    2    2
```

Alternatively using `chain.from_iterable` to flatten the lists first:

```
from itertools import chain

print (pd.DataFrame([chain.from_iterable(i.values()) for i in d.values()],
                    index=d.keys(),
                    columns=[f"{k}_{num}" for k, v in list(d.values())[0].items()
                             for num in range(len(v))]))

   1_0  1_1  1_2  2_0  2_1
x    2    5    6    7    6
y    0    4    8    8    1
z    8    0    9    2    2
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this certainly works, but I am looking for a highly optimised way because my real JSON file is > 200MB!

Comment: @pr94 sure. I added an alternative method for you to test.

Comment: @HenryYik - columns names are different

Comment: @jezrael Yes but he also said _the labelling of the columns do not necessarily have to be exactly this_ so :)

Comment: @HenryYik yes, but if you have an easy way to implement it, it would be preferred. It is nice that you have the row labeling also in the second option!

Comment: Thanks you very much!

Comment: @HenryYik I tested it on the real dataset. I am not sure what exactly went wrong but the data inside the df is sometimes incorrect. Do you have an explanation?

Comment: @pr94 I don't have access to your data so obviously i cant tell, but perhaps it is due to inconsistency between your entries.